# Let $f(x)=3x^2−14x+10$. What is the value of $x$ for which the tangent line to the graph of $y=f(x)$ is parallel to the $x$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=3x^2−14x+10$.
What is the value of $x$ for which the tangent line to the graph of $y=f(x)$ is parallel to the $x$-axis?

Comment: Please use proper formatting to make your question legible.

Comment: Graphically can you see why it must be at an extremum?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:Parallel to $x$-axis means the slope is $0$. So, differentiate the function and equating it with $0$, find $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint if you haven't had calculus yet: knowing that the tangent line will only be horizontal at the vertix, you need to use your algebraic skills to get this into the form $$y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)^2$$  From here can you tell what the vertix of this parabola is?